# Why is my regex allowing more than 1

Tags: php, regex

My url validation regex is allowing more than 1 `.` when the `www` rule next to it works fine.
Can u see why and how to solve it? And feel free to comment on my regex

```
function isurl($this_url)
{
        if(preg_match("/^((http|https):\/{2})+([w]{3})+([\.]{1})+([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+([\.]{1})+((a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwxz]|aero|arpa)|(b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|biz)|(c[acdfghiklmnorsuvxyz]|cat|com|coop)|d[ejkmoz]|(e[ceghrstu]|edu)|f[ijkmor]|(g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|gov)|h[kmnrtu]|(i[delmnoqrst]|info|int)|(j[emop]|jobs)|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|(m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|mil|mobi|museum)|(n[acefgilopruz]|name|net)|(om|org)|(p[aefghklmnrstwy]|pro)|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortvyz]|(t[cdfghjklmnoprtvwz]|travel)|u[agkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw])$/i", $this_url)) 
            {
            return true;
            }

}


$this_url = "http://www..domain.com";

if (isurl($this_url)) 
{echo "Success";} 
else 
{echo "Fail";}
```

Comment: It would **really** help if you could explain what the desired behavior is and also explain what your regex is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `+` in this `([\.]{1})+`, `+` mean one or more. try this

```
([\.]{1})
```

Answer (score 4):

> "([.]{1})+"

Plus sign means "once or more times".

Answer (score 4):

`([\.]{1})+` evaluates as `(.){1 or more times}`. On regular expressions, + is **NOT** a concatenation.

Comment: So I need to remove all the + signs in there?

Comment: @Norman yes, you do. and while you're at it, remove all `{1}`, too. they are redundant.

Comment: Right. Thanks. Did it. Works nicely now.